# How To Force Reboot With InstallShield LE That Comes With VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, setup-deployment, installshield-le

How do I force a reboot at the end of the installation from my app? Yes I am 100% sure I have a valid reason for this. But I can't seem to figure out how to make it reboot.

I'm using the IntallShield Limited Edition product that comes with Visual Studio 2012. If I go to the custom actions window, when I right click on the item for when the setup completes, and I try to choose the option to schedule a reboot, it is grayed out!

I assume this is because I have not paid InstallShield $4500 yet? What is the easiest way to force the reboot (for free).

Thanks,
JP

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked up whether this is in the limited edition or not, but in other editions, InstallShield conditions the `ScheduleReboot` action off of a property `ISSCHEDULEREBOOT`. If you can set `ISSCHEDULEREBOOT` (say from a custom action), that would be a much better approach to rebooting the machine than directly doing so, as it will ask the user and natively support the normal Windows Installer reboot-related properties.